# Will using body {font-size: 10px} change the way ems work?

Tags: css, font-size

I'm trying to design a responsive layout and I'm using a trick to make the use of EMs easier. In my body, I have this: `body {font-size: 10px}`.

Will this change the way EMs work?

If I set `p {font-size: 1em}` will it be 10px regardless of your screen size?

Comment: That's really two questions, isn't it? Also, that's exactly how `em`s are supposed to work - they're a relative unit, much like percents. As for setting font size proportional to the viewport size, you could try the [CSS3 viewport-relative units.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) No idea whether they're supported in browsers though.

Comment: Oh yeah, just noticed now. Going to remove the last one, since I can probably find it on google. So even if I set a fixed font size in body my ems will be relative to the user's screen/default font size?

Comment: No. `em`s are always relative to the containing element's font size. As far as I understand, `font-size: 1em;` is *exactly the same* as `font-size: 100%;`. There's also `rem`s , which is relative to the font size of the root element. This should be the user's default font size, unless you of course set a font size on the `html` element yourself: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Abodl

Comment: So if I don't set a font-size in my body and use ems for all the texts in the page then it will be relative to the screen size/default font size?

Comment: Yes, it will be relative to the root `<html>` elements font-size, which is 16px for most browsers

Comment: "16px for most browsers" - but not all.

Comment: @Gus "So if I don't set a font-size in my body and use ems for all the texts in the page" **No**, not exactly. I updated my example (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Abodl) to show that `em`s are relative to the *containing* element. If you have *nested* elements that all set sizes in `em`s, the size adjustments will multiply. If you set a font size on `body`, then any children of `body` will have `em`s relative to that size, and their children will inherit that size, but `rem` will still be relative to the browser default. (Because `body` isn't the root element of a HTML document.)

Comment: Also: [*How we learned to leave default font-size alone and embrace the em*](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/how_we_learned_to_leave_body_font_size_alone/). I'd also recommend going through A List Apart for more "best practices", they've been going on about responsive design for roughly ever now. (And subjectively speaking, 10px text is terrible.)

Comment: @Adrift - really almost any browser:  http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `font-size` does not change the way the `em` unit works.

If you set `p {font-size: 1em}`, then, with the usual CSS Caveats (other style sheets might set `font-size` on `p`, etc.), the font size in any `p` will be equal to the font size of its parent, which is what happens by default anyway via inheritance (when no style sheet sets `font-size` on the `p` element).

If a `p` element is a child of `body` and you have set `body {font-size: 10px}`, then, with the Caveats, the `p` element’s font size will be 10 CSS pixels. The size of a CSS pixel depends on the device and need not equal physical device pixel; see [5.2. Absolute lengths: the ‘cm’, ‘mm’, ‘in’, ‘pt’, ‘pc’, ‘px’ units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) in CSS Values and Units Module Level 3 CR (which is more realistic than CSS 2.1).